# Convert PImage to Mat - Java OpenCV in Processing IDE P3D (OpenGL) renderer

Tags: java, image, opencv, processing

I wrote a code to convert between OpenCV Mat to PImage (ARGB) and back. I use webcamera as input with captured by Processing video library. It works in Java2D renderer but not in P2D or P3D renderer. What migh be the issue?

It tried using `loadPixels()` and `updatePixels()` statements - it does not work. Also what is peculiar is that camera image in P3D renderer can not be copied to PImage with `pimage = cam.copy();` or `pimage = cam.get();` but it has to be assigned like pimage = cam; I dont understand why is that?

I am using native Opencv Java 3.4.

```
    import processing.video.*;
    Capture cam;
    import java.nio.*; //to convert Mat  PImage

    byte [] bArray;
    int [] iArray;
    int pixCnt1, pixCnt2;
    PImage camStream;// camera frame

    //----------------------
    void setup() {
      size(640, 480); //PImage to mat does not work with P2D for some reason?

      //size(640,480,P3D);// this does NOT WORK

      String[] cameras = Capture.list();

      if (cameras == null) {
        println("Failed to retrieve the list of available cameras, will try the default...");
        cam = new Capture(this, 640, 480);
      } 
      if (cameras.length == 0) {
        println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
        exit();
      } else {
        println("Available cameras:");
        //printArray(cameras);

        cam = new Capture(this, cameras[0]);    
        //cam = new Capture(this, 1280, 720, "c922 Pro Stream Webcam", 5);
        cam.start();
      }

      System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);  
      println(Core.VERSION);

      pixCnt1 = width*height*4;// number of bytes in the pixel buffer.
      pixCnt2 = width*height;//number of integers in the PImage pixels buffer.
      bArray = new byte[pixCnt1]; //temporary byte array buffer for OpenCV cv::Mat.
      iArray = new int[pixCnt2];//temporary integer array buffer for PImage pixels.

      camStream = createImage(640, 480, ARGB);
    }

    void draw() {
      background(0);

      if (cam.available() == true) {
        cam.read();

        camStream = cam;

        Mat frame = toMat(camStream ); //CvType=CV_8UC4
        //Mat undistorted = frame.clone();
        camStream = toPImage(frame);
      }

      image(camStream, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Convert PImage (ARGB) to Mat (CvType = CV_8UC4)
    Mat toMat(PImage image) {
      //image.loadPixels(); //???

      int w = image.width;
      int h = image.height;

      Mat mat = new Mat(h, w, CvType.CV_8UC4);
      byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*4];
      int[] data32 = new int[w*h];
      arrayCopy(image.pixels, data32);
      ByteBuffer bBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(w*h*4);
      IntBuffer iBuf = bBuf.asIntBuffer();
      iBuf.put(data32);
      bBuf.get(data8);
      mat.put(0, 0, data8);
      //image.updatePixels();
      return mat;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Convert Mat (CvType=CV_8UC4) to PImage (ARGB)
    PImage toPImage(Mat mat) {

      int w = mat.width();
      int h = mat.height();

      PImage image = createImage(w, h, ARGB);

      //image.loadPixels(); //???
      byte[] data8 = new byte[w*h*4];
      int[] data32 = new int[w*h];
      mat.get(0, 0, data8);
      ByteBuffer.wrap(data8).asIntBuffer().get(data32);
      arrayCopy(data32, image.pixels);
      //image.updatePixels(); //???
      return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting issue. It might have something to do with timing and pixel data access (which the 2D renderer might hide).

You could get around it by explicitly copying the data using [get()](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_get_.html):

```
void draw() {
  Mat frame = toMat(camStream ); //CvType=CV_8UC4
  camStream = toPImage(frame);
  image(camStream, 0, 0, 640, 480);
}

void captureEvent(Capture cam){
  cam.read();
  // make copy of the data
  camStream = cam.get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm. I have also spotted some problems when redeclaring PVectors variables with simple "=" and sometimes it was neede to use .copy() or mentioned .get() but I did not thought about it using it in this scenario. Still I do not understand the logic behind it...do you have some insight in the logic behind it?

Comment: @doku Regarding PVector `.copy()` it sounds like a scenario where you would manipulating references to the PVectors when you would need in independent copy of data. Imagine having two or more references to the same piece of data for difference reasons (stages of a rendering / simulation pipleline, etc.): if you change that reference in one place: it will affect the others. This where you would split the pipeline where up to a poin the data is the same, after which the data is copied so two independent functionalities can run without affecting each other. HTH

Comment: @doku also I thought I would point you to the [OpenCV Processing library](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing): could be handy. (e.g. `opencv.loadImage(camStream);` then `opencv.getGray()` or `opencv.getColor()` to get `Mat` and `opencv.getOutput()` to get the `PImage`. In between you can do filters/etc. work with Mat directly then `opencv.setColor()`/opencv.setGray();` or `OpenCV.toProcessing`